# PCMCIA and ExpressCard 54 - Are they interchangeable? (Adding firewire to laptop)

Tags: laptop, firewire, pcmcia

I'm trying to add firewire capabilities to my laptop.  I have an ExpressCard 54 slot, but I am having trouble finding a Firewire card for that.  I have found several PCMCIA cards, though.  They look similar in size, so I wasn't sure if they were interchangeable.

If they aren't, what can you recommend as an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are express card that adds firewire. You can see one there for exemple : http://www.sonnettech.com/product/fwusbexpresscard34.html

Answer (score 4):

They are not interchangeable. It is like comparing ISA to PCI cards. While they do have same purpose, connectors are not same.

Comment: Yeah, I feared that might be the case.  Thank you.

Comment: Worse. to PCIe.  (PCMCIA to ISA,  Cardbus to PCI,  ExpressCard 54 to a single PCI-e lane).